# Проблемы с z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

```css
.seo {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
  height: 328px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 480px;
}

.lefthand {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 39px;
  width: 66px;
  bottom: 108px;
  left: 116px;
  background-position: -70px -242px;
}
```

```html
<div class="seo">
  <div class="lefthand"></div>
</div>
```

Картинка из класса `lefthand` получается сверху картинки из `seo`, менял позиционирование, пытался найти ошибку, но так и не нашел. Помогите исправить! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ну логично. У вас lefthand является потомком seo. Это всё равно положить коробку на пол в комнате и ожидать, что рисунок на полу будет сверху рисунка на дне коробки

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский : D : D

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/166435/

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` работает не так. Каждый элемент `z-index` отличным от `auto` создаёт контекст, все внутренние элементы с `z-index`ом будут упорядочиваться внутри данного контекста.

Однако, есть другой способ помещения вложенного элемента за фон - использование отрицательного `z-index`а. Ещё понадобится перенести фон:

```css
.seo {
  position: relative;
  height: 328px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 480px;
}

.seo::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
}

.lefthand {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  z-index: -2;
  height: 39px;
  width: 66px;
  bottom: 108px;
  left: 116px;
  background-position: -70px -242px;
}
```

```html
<div class="seo">
  <div class="lefthand"></div>
</div>
```